# Ruby Curve Fitting (logarithmic regression) package

Tags: ruby, math, statistics

I am looking for a Ruby gem or library that does logarithmic regression (curve fitting to a logarithmic equation).  I've tried statsample (http://ruby-statsample.rubyforge.org/), but it doesn't seem to have what I'm looking for.  Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are familiar with ruby-toolbox.com but it helped me find a suitable library / plugin for most of my projects.

Answer (score 12):

Try using the 'statsample' gem. You can perform exponential, logarithmic, power, sinusoidal or any other transformation using similar methods. I hope this helps.

```
require 'statsample'

# Independent Variable
x_data = [Math.exp(1), Math.exp(2), Math.exp(3), Math.exp(4), Math.exp(5)]

# Dependent Variable
y_data = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]

# Logarithmic Transformation of X data 
# Math.log in Ruby has the base of Euler's number 'e' ~= '2.71828', 
# instead of the base '10'. Just a note.
log_x_data = x_data.map { |x| Math.log(x) }

# Linear Regression using the Logarithmic Transformation
x_vector = log_x_data.to_vector(:scale)
y_vector = y_data.to_vector(:scale)
ds = {'x'=>x_vector,'y'=>y_vector}.to_dataset
mlr = Statsample::Regression.multiple(ds,'y')

# Prints a statistical summary of the regression
print mlr.summary

# Lists the value of the y-intercept 
p mlr.constant

# Lists the coefficients of each casual variable. In this case, we have only one--'x'.
p mlr.coeffs

# The regression output produces the line y = 1 + 2*x, but 
# considering that we transformed x earlier, it really produces
# y = 1 + 2*ln(x).

# Bonus: The command below lists the methods contained in the instance variable, so that 
# you can get the R^2, SSE, coefficients, and t-values. I'll leave it commented out for now. 
# p mlr.methods
```

Comment: I was wondering how this code would look like if it was the case of a "logarithmic transformation". Im trying to calculate a logarithmic trend line but seems like the docs of statsample are out of date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently looking for something similar and came across this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/ruby-statistical-gem).

Three gems to interact with R from Ruby:

- **RinRuby** (https://sites.google.com/a/ddahl.org/rinruby-users/)
- **RSRuby** (https://github.com/alexgutteridge/rsruby)
- **Rserve** through the Rserve-Ruby-Client (https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client)

Another gem for LR in Ruby:

- **linear-regression-ruby** (http://code.google.com/p/linear-regression-ruby/)

I haven't tried anything yet, but I'm investigating what options there are for doing MLR in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Try Rumale and Numo::NArray
https://github.com/yoshoku/rumale

[image]

> Rumale (Ruby machine learning) is a machine learning library in Ruby. Rumale provides machine learning algorithms with interfaces similar to Scikit-Learn in Python. Rumale supports Linear / Kernel Support Vector Machine, Logistic Regression, Linear Regression, Ridge, Lasso, Factorization Machine, Naive Bayes, Decision Tree, AdaBoost, Gradient Tree Boosting, Random Forest, Extra-Trees, K-nearest neighbor classifier, K-Means, K-Medoids, Gaussian Mixture Model, DBSCAN, Power Iteration Clustering, Mutidimensional Scaling, t-SNE, Principal Component Analysis, and Non-negative Matrix Factorization.